# Cohomology of pushforwards of vector bundles over the projectivization of a vector bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $p:\mathcal E\to X$ be a vector bundle over a smooth projective variety $X$ and $p’:\mathbb P\mathcal E\to X$ its projectivization.

We consider, then,  two vector bundles: $\mathcal B$ over the total space of $\mathcal E$, and $\mathcal B’$ over the total space of the projectivization $\mathbb P \mathcal E$.

EDIT: $\mathcal B’$ is the bundle obtained by $\mathcal B$ projectivizing the fibers of $\mathcal E$.

Is it possible to deduce the cohomology of $p_*\mathcal B$ by the cohomology of $p’_*\mathcal B’$ or vice versa?

Comment: How are $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B'}$ related?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot some important information! I added it as an edit

Comment: $p$ is an affine map, so it has no higher cohomology (assuming you are talking about sheaf cohomology), while $p'$ typically will have higher cohomology. So, I am somewhat unclear about your question.